# Where to plug LED on Arduino due for blink demo?

Tags: arduino

so, I got a Arduino Due, but I am somewhat confused about the pin layout.

As a simple setup, I want to have some LEDs blinking. On my host laptop, I use Node and Johnny-five like here: https://github.com/rwaldron/johnny-five/wiki/Getting-Started

But when it comes to the Arduino board, I am confused.
I found a board schematic here: http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=132130.0

But how and where should I connect the LED to have some basic strobe.

[image: arduino due setup]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to that link you provided:

```
// Create an Led on pin 13
var led = new five.Led(13);
```

[image]

Connect the LED to pin 13 or any other pin as long as you modify this code.

Comment: There is already an onboard LED connected to digital pin 13 so for testing purpose there is no need for an external one.